# Expanding Search Box with Suggestion

Tags: javascript, css, semantic-ui

I have been looking at every tutorial and samples but unable to get this right. I need to recreate an animation on search box such that it expands to take the full width of the menu once hovered or clicked. Exactly like the header on firebase [website](https://firebase.google.com/docs/).

starting [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n3drq3nr/1/)

```
$( ".search" ).click(function() {
  $( ".search" ).css('width': '100%');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with pure-CSS.

Just set required width on the search box on `:focus` and `:hover`. For animation, I have applied `transition: all 1s ease-in-out` with `!important` as there is already a transition property on `.ui.input input`.

```css
.prompt {
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out !important;
    width: 180px;
}

.prompt:focus, 
.prompt:hover {
  width:  calc(100vw - 45px);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.js"></script>
<div class="ui top attached menu">
  <div class="ui dropdown icon item">
    <i class="wrench icon"></i>
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="item">
        <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
        <span class="text">New</span>
        <div class="menu">
          <div class="item">Document</div>
          <div class="item">Image</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Open...
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Save...
      </div>
      <div class="item">Edit Permissions</div>
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <div class="header">
        Export
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Share...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right menu">
    <div class="ui right aligned category search item">
      <div class="ui transparent icon input">
        <input class="prompt" type="text" placeholder="Search animals...">
        <i class="search link icon"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="results"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ui bottom attached segment">
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Nisarg. Amazing. One more thing. I updated my fiddle with your code https://jsfiddle.net/n3drq3nr/4/ and it is not expanding which changing width from 400px to 100% and also animation is not working. But overall this helps a lot. Thanks again

Comment: @SuperMan Looking at your fiddle, it seems certainly strange that width 100% is not working. My guess is that one of the parent element might be forcing the width on it. I'd probably try using `calc` in such cases to get full width on the element.

Comment: @SuperMan In this fiddle, I've set the width to be equal to full width minus the width of wrench icon. You can adjust it to get it to work the way you want though: https://jsfiddle.net/n3drq3nr/5/

Comment: I tried back and forth and could not adjust it. Thanks Nisarg and this definitely helps alot and hope I don't run into the problem when buttons are dynamically added to the menu.

Comment: I with the `calc` based width, you might have to adjust the width after adding buttons. Anyway, happy to help. Btw, you can mark helpful answers as accepted. Do read, if you haven't already:  [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: No need to use !important here, I would recommend using a specificity selector of higher importance like `.ui.right.aligned.category.search` or add id search and use `#search .search`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with pure CSS, no JS needed. Look into [css transitions](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)

```css
#search{
  width:200px;
}

#search:focus, #search:hover{
  width:100%;
  transition: width 2s;
}
```

```html
<input id="search"/>
```